# Is there any better way to create a real time leaderboard for heavy traffic webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I have made a leaderboard in a web app using datas fetched from mysql database in php.The webpage has other functionalities as well with other sql queries.The reference for leaderboard was

[what is the best practice leaderboard with php, mysql, memcached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112852/what-is-the-best-practice-leaderboard-with-php-mysql-memcached) ,

> the question that worries me is there a better approach to consider
>   for making leaderboard apps ?

Meanwhile i came across Firebase and was able to run code in Fiddle which is given below :

```
 var LEADERBOARD_SIZE = 6;

  var scoreListRef = new Firebase('https://i62qrqslypp.firebaseio-demo.com//scoreList');

  var htmlForPath = {};

  function handleScoreAdded(scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
    var newScoreRow = $("<tr/>");
    newScoreRow.append($("<td/>").append($("<em/>").text(scoreSnapshot.val().name)));
    newScoreRow.append($("<td/>").text(scoreSnapshot.val().score));


    htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.key()] = newScoreRow;

    // Insert the new score in the appropriate place in the table.
    if (prevScoreName === null) {
      $("#leaderboardTable").append(newScoreRow);
    }
    else {
      var lowerScoreRow = htmlForPath[prevScoreName];
      lowerScoreRow.before(newScoreRow);
    }
  }

  function handleScoreRemoved(scoreSnapshot) {
    var removedScoreRow = htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.key()];
    removedScoreRow.remove();
    delete htmlForPath[scoreSnapshot.key()];
  }

  var scoreListView = scoreListRef.limitToLast(LEADERBOARD_SIZE);


  scoreListView.on('child_added', function (newScoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
    handleScoreAdded(newScoreSnapshot, prevScoreName);
  });

  scoreListView.on('child_removed', function (oldScoreSnapshot) {
    handleScoreRemoved(oldScoreSnapshot);
  });


  var changedCallback = function (scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName) {
    handleScoreRemoved(scoreSnapshot);
    handleScoreAdded(scoreSnapshot, prevScoreName);
  };
  scoreListView.on('child_moved', changedCallback);
  scoreListView.on('child_changed', changedCallback);


  $("#scoreInput").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var newScore = Number($("#scoreInput").val());
      var name = $("#nameInput").val();
      $("#scoreInput").val("");

      if (name.length === 0)
        return;

      var userScoreRef = scoreListRef.child(name);

      userScoreRef.setWithPriority({ name:name, score:newScore }, newScore);
    }
  });
```

Output Leaderboard:

[image]

Im new to Firebase as well,please guide me on the issue

**[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/yh2ef8Lh/)**

Comment: So what is the actual question?

Comment: is there any alternative or which will be the best technique to follow ?..thank you @SamiKuhmonen